# Compare two lists and write for each item corresponding X column value

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have a list of users

```
resource = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

then I have a table

```
| Date     |   |  Resource    |
| -------- |   | ------------ |
| 2022-11-01   | ['A', 'B', 'C']   |
| 2022-11-12   | ['A', 'B']   |
| 2022-11-13   | ['B', 'C']   |
```

What I want is: to have a list of `Date` for each `Resource A, B, C`

So desired output could be a dictionary:

```
A: 2022-11-01
   2022-11-12
B: 2022-11-01
   2022-11-12
   2022-11-13
C: 2022-11-01   
   2022-11-13
```

Comment: Why isn't `C` in the dictionary?

Comment: Use nested loop. Loop over the rows in the dataframe, then loop over the resources. For each resource, append the date to the corresponding dictionary element. `collections.defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()` are useful to create the dictionary elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) at the end get the result as `dict` with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

```
dct = df.explode('Resource').groupby('Resource')['Date'].agg(list).to_dict()
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['2022-11-01', '2022-11-12'],
 'B': ['2022-11-01', '2022-11-12', '2022-11-13'],
 'C': ['2022-11-01', '2022-11-13']}
```